# Number of Combinations of a Team Scoring First in Soccer

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to know the number of combinations of a team scoring first, given a correct score. So for a final score of, say, m-n, there are

$\frac{(m+n)!}{(m!)(n!)}$

final paths to a correct score. In the case of 3-2, this would be:

$\frac{(5)!}{(3!)(2!)} = 35$ combinations of the goals occurring.

What I would like to know is, can we generalise for how many times a team scored *first* given we know that a team has scored $m$ goals in a game with $m + n$ goals?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How many combinations are there for a team to score first? If there are $m+n$ goals in a game, then there are $n$ ways for the m-team to score first.

Comment: Are you asking for the number of scoring sequences resulting in a match score of $m - n$ if the team which scores $m$ goals scores the first goal?

Comment: Hi @Newb yup, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: That would be the number of scoring sequences for the other goals i.e. for a match score of $(m-1) - n$

Comment: Alternatively, that team scores first with probability $\frac{m}{m+n}$ so just multiply your previous answer by that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the team which scores first scores $m$ goals in total and the other team scores $n$ goals, then the team which scores first must score $m - 1$ of the remaining $m + n - 1$ goals.  Therefore, there are
$$\binom{m + n - 1}{m - 1}$$
scoring sequences in which the team which scores first scores a total of $m$ goals while its opponent scores $n$ goals.